# Was bedeutet "Am Teller drehen"?

Tags: meaning

Was bedeutet "am Teller drehen"? Ich höre diese Phrase in einigen Liedern des HipHop-Genre. Was genau bedeutet sie?

Gibt es eine spezielle Kategorie von solchen Phrasen? Gibt es ähnliche oder Synonyme?

**EDIT:**
Ich vermute nicht dass sich das auf das Scratchen bezieht.
[Der Song in dem ich diese Phrase gehört habe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZt5wsLIFOE), 1:55 - 2:15

Answer (score 4):

Wenn der Kontext Hip-Hop ist, dann geht es ziemlich sicher um den **Platten**teller (siehe auch Antwort von musiKk).

Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch habe ich den Begriff aber noch nie gehört. Vermutlich soll es auch eine Anspielung auf die Redewendung "am Rad drehen" sein, was soviel bedeutet, wie wegen Überforderung dem Wahnsinn nahe zu sein (siehe auch "durchdrehen"). Woher diese Redewendungen wiederum kommen, könnte gut in einer neuen Frage behandelt werden.

Comment: Ups, da habe ich mir wohl zu viel Zeit mit dem Antworten gelassen. Sorry, @Pekka und @Klaus-Martin - wollte Euch nicht, Eure Ideen klauen. Als ich angefangen habe, zu schreiben, waren Eure Kommentare noch nicht da... :(

Comment: Keine Ursache. Nachdem er das Lied dazu verlinkt hat, denke ich, dass Deine Antwort die bessere ist.

Comment: Ich glaube (jetzt) auch dass es sich hier um "am Rad drehen" handelt.

Answer (score 3):

Mit Hip-Hop habe ich zwar nicht so viel zu tun, aber bei "am Teller drehen" kann es sich eigentlich nur um [scratchen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchen) handeln, also das Drehen der Schallplatte, während die Nadel auf der Platte bleibt.

Comment: +1 Siehe auch "Plattenteller": http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schallplatte

Comment: Ist das nicht auch eine Verballhornung von "am Rad drehen"?

Comment: Glaube ich kaum - es geht um einen realen Drehvorgang: http://youtu.be/Y6bapWp-4k0?t=48s

Comment: In dem Lied, dass er verlinkt hat, heisst es "...mein neuer Rappername, nein Spaß, ich dreh' nur am Teller, denn bisschen geisteskrank sein, ist eigentlich ganz fein". Er begründet also am "Teller drehen" mit "geisteskrank sein". Klingt für mich nach "am Rad drehen", was ja "verrückt werden" bedeutet.

Comment: @Klaus-Martin Scheuer, hmmm, obwohl ich das jetzt 1000 mal gehört habe, habe ich nicht so genau darauf geachtet, da ich mich auf das "Tellerdgedrehe" fokusiert habe. Vielen Dank!